# Nextjs app not running on port after deploying to VM (docker, kubernetes)

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, next.js

Trying to spin up Nextjs application on server by creating docker image and running it on a VM along with Kubernetes.

After deployment, I can see my nextjs pod running fine and even in logs it claimed that server has started. However I can't access the web via browser nor curl the url.

**I have tried a few things**

1. Changing from port 3000 to 5000 to confirm port 3000 is not blocked by whatever reason
2. Check result of `lsof -i :5000`, I see nothing showing up.
3. Check result of `curl http://localhost:5000`, I got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused` return.
4. Verified my nextjs pod's log, as below

```
> begin-next@0.1.0 dev /usr/src/app
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:5000, url: http://localhost:5000
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.2s (171 modules)
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
```

**Code reference**

Below is the `Dockerfile` and `deployment.yaml` use

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12

ENV PORT 5000

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Installing dependencies
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Copying source files
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Building app
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 5000

# Running the app
CMD "npm" "run" "dev"

# Running the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Deployment Yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nextjs-web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nextjs-web
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nextjs-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nextjs
        image: maskedPath/dockerimages/nextjs:1234
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nextjs-web
spec:
  selector:
    app: nextjs-web
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
```

**Other details**

Describe pod

```
Name:         nextjs-web-c9cfb675d-6thbx
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         maskedData
Start Time:   Thu, 21 Apr 2022 15:23:56 +0000
Labels:       app=nextjs-web
              pod-template-hash=c9cfb675d
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           maskedData
IPs:
  IP:           maskedData
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nextjs-web-c9cfb675d
Containers:
  nextjs:
    Container ID:   containerd://c7bbad112c6915af0aea2a7a7e1a7f42a87840e7e22ca1fe49afdc0000000000
    Image:          maskedData/dockerimages/nextjs:1234
    Image ID:       maskedData/dockerimages/nextjs@sha256:000000000036f0e0728c128322f95a9585b6724332d3f853e7f240a8df2b0ad3
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 21 Apr 2022 15:24:09 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-n72pn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-n72pn:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-n72pn
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally have it work, the **catch is to expose the app in services** via type load balancer. Hence this app will be accessible to the internet world.

Command below can be use to expose.

```
kubectl expose deployment nextjs-web --type=LoadBalancer --name=nextjs-web
```